# How to send messages from Gmail using my Outlook.Office account?

Tags: gmail, alias, outlook-on-the-web

I'm using Gmail for handling all my emails. At work though I was given a new outlook.office account (I don't know what is the precise status of the email accounts supplied by my work, but they are accessed by using something like 
`https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=<url of work>`).

I want to use the Gmail client, so when I send emails, they will be sent as if they're from my work emails.

This is usually possible with the "Send As" functionality in Gmail account setting. But I can't find how to do it for outlook.office email addresses.

Is this even possible? And how?

Comment: Presumably this is "Office 365"? AFAIK the "Send Mail As" functionality is the only way to be able to send from Gmail using another address (at least in personal Gmail). In which case, you'll need the SMTP details, as for any external email account. See: [POP and IMAP settings for Outlook Office 365 for business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c) However, this sounds like something you'll need to check with your place of work.

Comment: Yes, I succeeded to do it already, and indeed your link gives the correct smtp details. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I've posted that as an answer, so it can be removed from the unanswered question queue.

Answer (score 1):

This is presumably "Office 365". As far as I known, the "Send Mail As" functionality is the only way to be able to *send* from Gmail using another address (at least in personal Gmail). In which case, you'll need the SMTP details, as for any external email account.

Reference:
[POP and IMAP settings for Outlook Office 365 for business](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c).

However, this sounds like something you should perhaps check with your place of work. By using an external (non-IMAP) email client your sent emails are not going to be stored with your account, which is going to make it harder for the bosses/administrators, should they need access to your account. Although there should still be an SMTP log on the mailserver.